# Is it possible to rotate a trivector?

Tags: vectors, clifford-algebras

We can rotate a vector anda bivector by applying a rotor to it.
But can we rotate a trivector with rotors?
If so, how?

Comment: @Henry I've already read it but I can't find something useful for my question.

Answer (score 2):

In 3 dimensions, all vectors commute with trivectors. For example,

$$e_1(e_1e_2e_3)=e_1(e_1e_2)e_3=e_1(-e_2e_1)e_3=-e_1e_2(e_1e_3)=-e_1e_2(-e_3e_1)=+(e_1e_2e_3)e_1$$

and thus all multivectors commute with trivectors. (This is false in higher dimensions.) So applying a rotor to a trivector

$$RTR^{-1}=TRR^{-1}=T$$

does nothing. Geometrically, rotating 3D space in itself doesn't change it to a different 3D space, and doesn't change the volume of anything.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that mr_e_man's answer applies to three dimensions, but not to four:

$e_1(e_2 e_3 e_4) = -e_2 e_1 e_3 e_4 = e_2 e_3 e_1 e_4 = -e_2 e_3 e_4 e_1$

Define $R = e_1 e_4$ and $\bar R = e_4 e_1$. Apply this rotor to the trivector $e_1 e_2 e_3$:

$$R e_1 e_2 e_3 \bar R = 
e_1 e_4 e_1 e_2 e_3 e_4 e_1 =
- e_4 e_2 e_3 e_4 e_1 =
 e_4 e_2 e_4 e_3 e_1 =
 - e_4 e_4 e_2 e_3 e_1 =
 - e_2 e_3 e_1 =
 e_2 e_1 e_3 = 
 - e_1 e_2 e_3$$

So, if you are working in four dimensions, you can rotate a trivector.

Comment: You should post this as a question, not an answer.